How to read in an SQL query with a DECLARE statement in to R
I have the following code in R that I use to read in an SQL query, I want to keep it in the .sql format (rather than pasting the whole query in to R) as we regularly make changes to this file and have a lot of R files reading from it.
Start_date <- '2022-07-01'
End_date <- '2023-06-30'

#Connect to the server through the odbc connection setup on windows
db_conn<-odbcConnect("DSNconnect", rows_at_time=1)

query <- read_file("filepath.sql")

query <- gsub("\r", " ", query)
query <- gsub("\t", " ", query)

q <- sqlQuery(db_conn,query,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

odbcClose(db_conn)

The query has been changed to have DECLARE statements at the beginning so the dates to run the query for are set but I am getting the following error with this new addition:
"[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."
This is what the DECLARE statement looks like
DECLARE @StartDate date;
SET @StartDate = '",Start_date,"';
DECLARE @EndDate date;
SET @EndDate =  '",End_date,"';

SELECT ...
FROM ... 
WHERE (StartDateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)

This query works fine in SQL and when pasting the full query in to R (rather than reading it from a file), I have tried multiple different date/time formats but nothing seems to be working. Any advice is appreciated!

You should pass the parameters to your query via the R calling function.  The precise syntax may depend on your drivers and R libraries.  But using DBI may look something like: q <- sqlQuery(db_conn,"select ... from ... where StartDateTime between $1 and $2",params=list(Start_date,End_date))
